# Sharepoint Designer crashing when trying to add new External Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-designer, external-content-type

Sharepoint Designer is crashing when trying to add new External Content Type with below error message:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: spdesign.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 14.0.4750.1000
  Problem Signature 03: 4b8baffb
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 2.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4ca2b851
  Problem Signature 07: 4212
  Problem Signature 08: a9
  Problem Signature 09: System.TypeInitialization
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never experience it, but probably these two things helps you:

1. Close SPD and clear its cache. It is located here:

   %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache
   %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache
2. If it doesn't help, try to uninstall SPD and install the latest version of it.

Clear the cache by pasting the following in cmd:

```
    cd "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache"
    del *.web /S /Q "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache"
    cd "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\"
    rmdir /S /Q "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\."
    mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache"
    dir "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache"
    dir "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache"
    pause
```

Comment: It worked after reinstallation.